# How to get messages sent to http://localhost:7777/ through a Linux command line?

Tags: websocket, command-line, command

I would like to check messages sent to my 7777 port, namely, http://localhost:7777/. I am on Linux and want to do it through command line. Which command line should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use the tool `netcat`? Try `nc localhost 7777`. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Simple command :- nc -vz [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) 7777

nc -vz (website) (port number)

Comment: Thanks. Can I also use this for localhost? Sorry no idea about network stuff.

Comment: Yupp for sure :)